# Error: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

***When I try to install any package via terminal in Ubuntu 20.04 I got  the following error:-***

```
dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk depends on ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (= 1:20.04.37); however:
  Package ubuntu-release-upgrader-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
 ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ` please [edit] your question to show us the output.

Comment: Million thanks ! It worked!!